# WSO2-How to load CSV file on a SharePoint folder? FTP or SharePoint Connector?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to upload a csv file on a SharePoint folder.
This csv file is downloaded from a url at run time.
As SharePoint is not a FTP server,i am planning to use SharePoint connector.

In the document the create file within folder operation has below elements.

```
<sharepoint.createFileWithinFolder>
    <folderName>{$ctx:folderName}</folderName>
    <fileName>{$ctx:fileName}</fileName>
    <fileContent>{$ctx:fileContent}</fileContent>
    <overwrite>{$ctx:overwrite}</overwrite>
</sharepoint.createFileWithinFolder>
```

Below is the example they have given

```
{

  "apiUrl":"https://wso.sharepoint.com",
  "overwrite":"true",
  "folderName":"/Document",
  "fileName":"file.json",
  "fileContent":"{\"a\":\"b\"}",
  "accessToken":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "blocking":"true"
}
```

Has anybody used SharePoint connector's createFileWithinFolder operation?
In File content should we pass the actual file content?
my csv file has thousands of rows.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using File Connector along with SharePoint Connector. You can refer [1] to get an idea to use file connector where using FileRead operation, read a content of the file and use that content for another purpose.

In this sample, we read the file, get the content and set that content in a property. Then we use that property for future use.

```
<fileconnector.read>  
   <source>{$ctx:source}</source>  
   <contentType>{$ctx:contentType}</contentType>  
   <filePattern>{$ctx:filePattern}</filePattern>  
  </fileconnector.read>  
  <enrich>  
   <source type="body" clone="true" />  
   <target type="property" property="mailContent" />  
  </enrich>  
  <log level="custom">  
   <property name="!!!!!!!!! fileReadContent !!!!!!!!!!!!" expression="get-property('mailContent')" />  
  </log>
```

[1] http://vsvives.blogspot.com/2017/03/integrate-wso2-esb-file-connector-with.html

Comment: Thank you!
I have the File content stored in a Property.
But how to upload it on SharePoint? 
Our SharePoint is not a FTP server neither it is on-Premises SP.
Out SharePoint site is in cloud.
so will the Share Point connector work?

Comment: Now, we have set the property mailContent and it is holding file content. In SharePoint connector, we can set like " <fileContent>{$ctx:mailContent}</fileContent>" to pass the value. 

<sharepoint.createFileWithinFolder>
    <folderName>{$ctx:folderName}</folderName>
    <fileName>{$ctx:fileName}</fileName>
    <fileContent>{$ctx:mailContent}</fileContent>
    <overwrite>{$ctx:overwrite}</overwrite>
</sharepoint.createFileWithinFolder>

I think it should work.

Comment: Thank you Vivek for your reply.
But one question -  will SharePoint Connector work for SharePoint site in cloud?

Comment: I think, it should work as mentioned in  https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service